# SQL selects not being commited results in caching

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I am using Tomcat and a JDBC connection pool with a mysql database. When a java.sql.Connection is created and #setAutoCommit(false) is set, and a select statement is performed without a commit, followed by closing the connection, it appears to return a cached connection back to the pool. Subsequents connections created afterwards where identical selects are executed return stale data from the database. This behavior seems odd in that I am forced to commit sessions where only selects are performed, otherwise I cannot see changes reflected by another node. Is there a way around this behavior, or do I have to commit every select?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: Set `rollbackOnReturn` or `commitOnReturn` attributes to true in the Tomcat connection pool configuration, see this link: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Tomcat_JDBC_Enhanced_Attributes. If autocommit is false, you **must** explicitely commit or rollback the transaction.

Comment: Question is, why do I **have** to commit when I haven't made any changes to the underlying database. This sort of behavior seems odd. One would expect calling .close() on the connection would be all you would have to do to release this connection to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue falls on how the contract is defined for the connection API. The commit[1] and rollback[2] methods are when the locks are released on the database. Since I wasn't committing or rolling back after the selects, these locks are maintained as the connection is returned back to the pool. One therefore must commit or rollback after doing selects so one can release the lock maintained in the connection.

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit()
[2] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback()